# Adding column of ones to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to simply add a column of ones to a numpy array but cannot find any easy solution to what I feel should be a straightforward answer. The number of rows in my array may change therefore the solution needs to generalise.

```py
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,45,23,56,34,23], 
              [2,46,24,57,35,23]])
```

My desired output:

```py
array([[ 1, 45, 23, 56, 34, 23, 1],
       [ 2, 46, 24, 57, 35, 23, 1]])
```

I have tried using `np.append` and  `np.insert`, but they either flatten the array or replace the values.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I have tried using np.append and np.insert..."*  Show *exactly* what you tried.  You might need just a small change to the shapes of the inputs that you used.

Comment: Did you see this line in `np.append`?  "If `axis` is not  given, both `arr` and `values` are flattened before use.
"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do `hstack`:

```
np.hstack((X,np.ones([X.shape[0],1], X.dtype)))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1, 45, 23, 56, 34, 23,  1],
       [ 2, 46, 24, 57, 35, 23,  1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [numpy.insert](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) following way:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,45,23,56,34,23], [2,46,24,57,35,23]])
X1 = np.insert(X, X.shape[1], 1, axis=1)
print(X1)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1 45 23 56 34 23  1]
 [ 2 46 24 57 35 23  1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append`, but you have to tell it which `axis` you want it to work along:

```
np.append(X, [[1],[1]],  axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.c_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html?highlight=c_#numpy.c_)

```
np.c_[X, [1, 1]]
```